# How to handle multiple forms in the same view?

Tags: forms, cakephp

I have a default form for my specific view.

Through an element I (dinamically) include another view (using view extension) in order to provide an upload form.

My problem is that the second form seems to submit the first one.

**Default form**

```
<div class="content-box-content">
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->create("WebSubject", array(
                'inputDefaults' => array(
                    'error' => array(
                        'attributes' => array(
                            'wrap' => 'span', 
                            'class' => 'input-notification error png_bg'
                        )                   
                    )
                )
            ));
        ?>

        <?=$this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'))?>

        <?=$this->Form->input('title', array('class' => "text-input small-input", 'label' => 'Denumire'))?>

        <?=$this->Form->input('description', array('type' => 'textarea', 'label' => 'Descriere', 'id' => 'description'))?>

        <?=$this->Form->input('description_long', array('type' => 'textarea', 'label' => 'Continut', 'id' => 'description_long'))?>

        <?=$this->Form->submit('Salveaza', array('class' => "button"))?>
    </div>
```

**This way I include the element**

```
<div class="tab-content default-tab" id="fotoUploadTab">
            <?php
                echo $this->element('file_upload_form', array(
                        'view' => 'upload_admin',
                        'webFileType' => 'image',
                        'redirect' => $SHT['here']
                    )
                );
            ?>
            <div class="tab-content default-tab">
                Lista imagini
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Element code**

```
<?php
    $view = (isset($view)) ? $view : "upload_admin";
    $webFileType = (isset($webFileType)) ? $webFileType : "image";
    $redirect = (isset($redirect)) ? $redirect : "/";
?>
<?php 
    $this->extend("/WebFiles/".$view);   
?>
```

**Extended View code**

```
<div class="tab-content default-tab">

    <?php echo $this->Form->create("WebFile", array('action' => '/', 'type' => 'file')); ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="" />
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('entity_id', array('type' => 'hidden')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('entity_table_name', array('type' => 'hidden')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('type', array('type' => 'hidden')); ?>

    <?php echo $this->Form->input('title', array('class' => "text-input small-input", 'label' => 'Denumire')); ?>   
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('description', array('class' => "text-input small-input", 'label' => 'Descriere')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Upload', array('class' => 'button')); ?>

</div>
```

As seen in the last snippet, I tried to force the last form by providing an action url, but on submiting it, it sends data as the first one does.

How should I handle this ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to have both forms, the one from parent and the other from the child view/element make sure you call $this->Form->end() in both templates and that you are not nesting a form inside the other. Probably, in your case, just by adding end() to both forms will solve your issue.

As a side note, you cannot have a parent view opening a Form with $this->Form->create() and inject fields into it using the child view, basically because you need create() to be called before any input is rendered and parent views are rendered after the child is executed.